# PostgreSQL serial pattern

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, auto-increment, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Is it possible to declare a `serial` field in Postgres (9.0) which will increment based on a pattern?

For example:

```
 Pattern: YYYY-XXXXX
 where YYYY is a year, and XXXXX increments from 00000 - 99999.
```

Or should I just use a trigger?

**EDIT:** I prefer the year to be auto-determined based, maybe, on server date. The `XXXXX` part does start with 00000 for each year and "resets" to 00000 then increments again to 99999 when the year part is modified.

Comment: I don't see anything in the AutoIncrement documentation that suggests that you can supply a pattern.  Looks like a Trigger is probably your best bet.

Comment: Oh, how sad. I cannot also find something like this in Google. I'll accept your answer if you can repost it below.

Comment: I agree with Robert Harvey，may be you shoud format the value in your program before insert into the table.

Comment: Thanks for the reaffirmation. :) I was hoping there was an "automatic" way of doing this, but sadly there is currently no way of automatically doing it (except via triggers).

Comment: Is it implied by the pattern that the rightmost counter should be reset when the year changes? Is YYYY always the year of the insert, or any year? The question is too vague.

Comment: @shippou: This can be done without triggers. Clarify your question. How is the year determined? Does the XXX part start with 0 for each year? What range of years is possible?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I do prefer the year to be auto-determined based, maybe, on server date. the XXXXX part does start with 0 for each year. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a separate `SEQUENCE` for each year, so that each sequence keeps track of one year - even after that year is over, should you need more unique IDs for that year later.

This function does it *all*:
 <sub>Improved with input from [@Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818688/igor-romanchenko) and [@Clodoaldo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131874/clodoaldo) in the comments.</sub>

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_year_id(y text = to_char(now(), 'YYYY'))
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
BEGIN

LOOP
   BEGIN
      RETURN y ||'-'|| to_char(nextval('year_'|| y ||'_seq'), 'FM00000');

   EXCEPTION WHEN undefined_table THEN   -- error code 42P01
      EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE year_' || y || '_seq MINVALUE 0 START 0';
   END;
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_year_id();
```

Returns:

```
2013-00000
```

Basically this returns a `text` of your requested pattern. Automatically tailored for the current year. If a sequence of the name `year_<year>_seq` does not exist yet, it is created automatically and `nextval()` is retried.

Note that you cannot have an [overloaded function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-overload.html) without parameter at the same time (like my previous example), or Postgres will not know which to pick and throw an exception in despair.

Use this function as `DEFAULT` value in your table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id text DEFAULT f_year_id(), ...)
```

Or you can get the next value for a year of your choice:

```
SELECT f_year_id('2012');
```

Tested in Postgres 9.1. Should work in v9.0 or v9.2 just as well.

To understand what's going on here, read these chapters in the manual:

[CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)
[CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createsequence.html)
[39.6.3. Simple Loops](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONTROL-STRUCTURES-LOOPS)
[39.5.4. Executing Dynamic Commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)
[39.6.6. Trapping Errors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)
[Appendix A. PostgreSQL Error Codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/errcodes-appendix.html)
[Table 9-22. Template Pattern Modifiers for Date/Time Formatting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIMEMOD-TABLE)

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas and code! I've never thought of this. :)

Comment: Why dynamic SQL for the `SELECT` ? The whole `EXECUTE .. RETURN;` can be replaced with something like `RETURN y ||'-'|| to_char(nextval('year_'|| y ||'_seq'), 'FM00000');`

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Good point. Dynamic SQL is only needed for the sequence creation. I improved the answer with your hint. Adapted the `RETURN` type to agree with it.

Comment: To make the _even after that year is over_ part true you should pass the year as a parameter.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Well, the sequence exists and can be used independently of the function once created. I inlined the date because the OP asks for the `year to be auto-determined`.

Comment: It would be auto-determined if `(id text DEFAULT f_year_id(extract(year from now())), ...)`. Then later he would not need to discover the sequence name nor how to operate it.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: That's a good idea! I incorporated it into the answer. Added a warning to go along with it.

Comment: @Erwin And in the process I learned how to create an optional parameter! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will form this value (YYYY-XXXXX) and set this function as a default for a column.

Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html).

Comment: Oh. Nice idea! :) This is a cleaner approach, IMHO, than defining an explicit trigger.